# FB.Data.query and where to find the Facebook database scheme?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi we've implemented the following code

INIT block (**WORKS**)

```
FB.init({
    appId: 'apiID',
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth: true,  // enable OAuth 2.0
    xfbml: true,   // parse XFBML
    frictionlessRequests: true
});
```

LOGIN block (**WORKS**)

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      console.log('User logged and fully authorize the app.');

    } else {
      console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
  }, {scope: 'email,user_location,friends_location'});
```

DATA RETRIEVE block (**DON'T WORK**)

```
var friends = FB.Data.query('SELECT uid, name, location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 15) AND has_added_app=0');

FB.Data.waitOn([friends], function() {
  FB.Array.forEach(friends.value, function(row) {
      console.log(row);
  });
});
```

The last problem does not occur for "SELECT uid, name FROM user ...".

Does anyone get an idea of the DB scheme of the facebook's "user" and "friend" tables? Other tables which can be accessed by "FB.Data.query"?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

CORRECT DATA RETRIEVE block (**WORKs**)

```
var friends = FB.Data.query('SELECT uid, name, hometown_location, current_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 15) AND has_added_app=0');

FB.Data.waitOn([friends], function() {
  FB.Array.forEach(friends.value, function(row) {
      console.log(row);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification for the [Facebook Query Language](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) (FQL) is available with the rest of the Facebook developer documentation, including schemas for the [user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) and [friend](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/) tables.

Comment: Thank you brother, you saved me. Really no way to find it on facebook developers!